# Compiler error after increasing size of automatic arrays in C

Tags: c, macros

I am trying to calculate a correlation measure for 18456 genes but the compiler (Dev C) exits after increasing macros `GENE` or `INDEX` to a value between 4000 and 5000 or bigger. For example it works well with:

```
# define GENE 4000
# define INDEX 3000
```

but not with:

```
#define GENE 5000 
#define INDEX 100
```

The input file is a space delimited text file with 18456 rows and 57 columns. 
Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <limits.h>
#define GENE 5000
#define N 57
#define INDEX 1000


int main (void) {

clock_t start, stop;
double t = 0.0;

int i, j, p, q, wp, wq;
double x;
double *S_matrix = (double *)malloc(INDEX * GENE * sizeof(double));
double sum_S, S_max;
double S[11] = {0};
double r = 0.0, xbar = 0.0, ybar = 0.0, sx = 0.0, sy = 0.0;

// read E matrix

FILE *fq;
double E[GENE][N] = {{0}};

if ((fq = fopen("E_disease.txt", "r")) == NULL ) 
{
     printf("Error\n");
     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

fq = fopen("E_disease.txt","r");
printf("\n");

for (i=0;i<GENE;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<N;j++)
    {
        fscanf(fq,"%lf",&x);
        E[i][j] = x;
    }
}


printf("\n");
fclose(fq);


// calculate correlation

assert((start = clock())!=-1);

for(p=0; p < INDEX; p++)
{
    for(q=0; q < GENE; q++)
    {
        for(i=0; i<11; i++)
        {

            /*compute xbar */
            for(j = i; j < N; j++) 
            {
                xbar += E[p][j];
            }

            xbar /= N;

            /*compute ybar*/
            for(j = i; j < N; j++) 
            {
                ybar += E[q][j];
            }

            ybar /= N;

            /* compute standard deviation of x*/
            for(j = i; j < N; j++) 
            {
                sx += (E[p][j] - xbar) * (E[p][j] - xbar);
            }

            sx = sqrt(sx);

            /* compute standard deviation of y */
            for(j = i; j < N; j++) 
            {
                sy += (E[q][j] - ybar) * (E[q][j] - ybar);
            }

            sy = sqrt(sy);

            /*compute r, the correlation coefficient between the two arrays */
            for( j = i; j < N; j++ ) 
            {
                r += (((E[p][j] - xbar)/sx) * ((E[q][j] - ybar)/sy));
            }

            r /= (N); 

            if(r>0)
            {
                S[i] = r;
            }
            else if(r<=0)
            {
                S[i] = 0;
            }

         }


         for(j=0, sum_S=0; j<11; j++)
         {  
             sum_S += S[j];
         }


         for(j=0, S_max = 0; j<11; j++)
         {
            if(S[j] > S_max)
            {
                S_max = S[j];
            }
         }

      S_matrix[p*GENE + q] = sum_S/(11*S_max);

  }

}

FILE * fs;

fs = fopen ("s_matrix.txt", "w+");

for(wp=0; wp<INDEX; ++wp)
{
    for(wq=0; wq<GENE; ++wq)
    {

        fprintf(fs, "%lf", S_matrix[wp*GENE + wq]);
        fprintf(fs, "\t");
    }

    fprintf(fs, "\n");
    printf("\n");
}

fclose(fs);

stop = clock();
t = (double) (stop-start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;


printf("Run time: %f\n", t);    

//print results 



//return (0);

getchar();

}
```

Let me simplify the code. When I ran the code below, a couple of times, it generally exited immediately. One time, it said that it could not find something like `0xff12345`. Another time it printed out `S_matrix[55]` when I defined constants inside main (the rest of the code is same) like `int GENE=100;` but just one time. Is that mean a memory leak? It does not give an error message when I compile it but are defining matrices and assigning values to them true?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <limits.h>
#define GENE 100
#define N 57
#define INDEX 10




int main (void) {

//int GENE = 100;
//int N = 57;
//int INDEX = 10;
int i, j; 
double x;
double *S_matrix = (double *)malloc(INDEX * GENE * sizeof(double));
double *E = (double*)malloc(GENE*N*sizeof(double));


// read E matrix

FILE *fq;


if ((fq = fopen("E_control.txt", "r")) == NULL ) 
{
     printf("Error\n");
     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

fq = fopen("E_control.txt","r");
printf("\n");

for (i=0;i<GENE;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<N;j++)
    {
        fscanf(fq,"%lf",&x);
        E[i*GENE+j] = x;
    }
}


printf("\n");
fclose(fq);

for(i=0; i<INDEX; i++)
{
         for(j=0; j<GENE; j++)
         {        
              S_matrix[i*INDEX+j]=i*j;
         }
}

printf("%f " , S_matrix[55]);


free(S_matrix);
S_matrix=NULL;
free(E);
E=NULL;
return(0);
getchar();
getchar();

}
```

Comment: Is it failing when trying to allocate memory?

Comment: Describe how it does not work.  Compile time failure? Run time crash? any error messages?

Comment: @ abelenky It is run time crash. @WhozCraig By the I guess that I've talked too early. I was writing `S_matrix` into the files as 1000x18456 matrices. It was working well when `E` is static but the run time was increasing in each step and started to exit again in the 12th turn.

Answer (score 4):

You're attempting to reserve **2280000** bytes of stack space (actually more) in `main()` because of a overtly large fixed array declaration. Specifically, this line:

```
double E[GENE][N] = {{0}};
```

equates to

```
double E[5000][57] = {{0}};
```

At 8-bytes per double, thats highly likely to be blowing out your stack. Use dynamic allocation for that array instead. For example:

```
double (*E)[N] = malloc(5000*sizeof(*E));
```

And don't forget to free it when you're done.

Global fixed allocation will also work (i.e. declare it as a global *outside* the `main()` function block.

```
static double E[GENE][N];

int main()
{
    ... your code ...
}
```

Any method you choose has potential advantages and pitfalls, so plan accordingly.

Comment: What is the limitation on heap and stack space allotted to a program, generally speaking?

Comment: @Kunal Its entirely implementation dependent. There is no definitive answer that covers all platforms.

Comment: So, if I have a cross-platform application that needs reasonably large arrays, dynamic allocation is the safer way to go?

Comment: @Kunal in comparison to risking a stack overreach? Yes. Obviously management of them is more tedious.

Comment: Thanks a lot Craig! You saved my thesis.

Comment: Found the problem with the static `E` version.  I forgot to assign `NULL` to S_matrix after freeing it and to unmask the `return(0);`. Thanks again.